# mutate the new data frame if email and unique ID is duplicate

Tags: r

I have a sample data frame and I want to check if the values are duplicate and mutate new columns as 1,0 for duplicate. I am trying like below but this isn't working for me.

```
df4 <- data.frame(emp_id =c("DEV-2962","KTN_2252","ANA2719","ITI_2624","DEV2698","HRT2921","","KTN2624","DEV2698","ITI2535","DEV2698","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                  email = c("akash.dev@abcd.com","rahul.singh@abcd.com","salman.abbas@abcd.com","ram.lal@abcd.com","ram.lal@xyz.com","prabal.garg@xyz.com","sanu.ali@abcd.com","kunal.singh@abcd.com","lakhan.tomar@abcd.com","praveen.thakur@abcd.com","sarman.ali@abcd.com","zuber.khan@dkl.com","giriraj.singh@dkl.com","lokesh.sharma@abcd.com","pooja.pawar@abcd.com","nikita.sharma@abcd.com"))
                  

ID = "emp_id"
Email = "email"

ID <- sym(ID)
Email <- sym(email)


df4 <- df4 %>% group_by(!!ID) %>% 
  mutate(Flag=1:n(),`Duplicate_ID`=ifelse(Flag==1,0,1)) %>% select(-Flag)

df4 <- df4 %>% filter(!is.na(!!Email)) %>% group_by(!!Email) %>%
  mutate(Flag=1:n(),`Duplicate_email`=ifelse(Flag==1,0,1)) %>% select(-Flag) %>% ungroup(.)
```

there can be different names in data frame for Name and email so i also want to fixed it.
also I want to give input parameter for user to give names of columns according to its data frame.
and i will recall it in my script. do we have any suggestion for that...??

like here i am using sym for fix the parameter in script.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldRm4.png)

Comment: Can you show your expected output? The first code is working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of getting into non-standard evaluation try with `across`. Also as far as I could read your code you are trying to assign 0 to first instance of the value in column and 1 for all the duplicates. You can do this `duplicated` so no need for `group_by`, `ifelse` etc.

```
library(dplyr)

ID = "emp_id"
Email = "email"

df4 <- df4 %>% 
  mutate(across(c(ID, Email), ~as.integer(duplicated(.)), .names = 'flag_{col}'))
```

Comment: I don't see it's need for this use-case.